# website be opened with redirection from stranger domaine

Tags: django, heroku, dns

my problem is:
I own a website developed with django framework and uploaded in heroku.
my domain is "OnlyMyDomain.com", but "StrangeDomaine.com" calls my website with a redirect. in other words when you go to StrangeDomaine.com, my website is opened even if the address change to OnlyMyDomain.com.
I tried in my `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['OnlyMyDomain.com']
```

Please can someone explain to me where the problem is coming from? and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. It seems that you define a **permanent redirection (301)** from **StrangeDomain.com** to **OnlyMyDomain.com**. Then request  url will be updated, then `StrangeDomain.com` becomes `OnlyMyDomain.com`. If you want to avoid that, just remove this redirection.

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated. The new URL
>   should be provided in the Location field included with the response.

Wiki : [HTTP 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

Comment: am not the owner of StrangeDomain.com . i want that my wesite could be loaded only if u directly type OnlyMyDomain.com

Comment: You can't do anything. Just contact owner of this domain to ask him to stop this redirection. Use **whois** to get domain information